# Finding and deleting one record from two tables ? MySQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have two MySQL tables, one with the field Username and the other User_Name, is it possible to find a record in one of the tables and delete it? I've tried the following but it didnt work...

```
DELETE FROM JB_Employer, JB_Jobseeker WHERE Username='$userName' OR User_Name='$userName'
```

I feel as though I'm missing something obvious..

Thanks.
Kai

Comment: Doesn't that throw an error? Because User_name field doesn't exists on JB_Employer..

Comment: Maybe you can do this: `WHERE JB_Employer.Username='$userName' OR JB_Jobseeker.User_Name='$userName'`

Comment: You'll want to review the multi-table DELETE syntax: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html

Comment: Yes I get an error, I figured it would but I cant quite work out the correct method. The Username field is in the JB_Employer table and the User_Name field is in the JB_Jobseeker table if it matters.

Comment: Tried to put table names in where clause?

Comment: Try what @Kristian is saying. I was going to answer with that, but I don't want to steal Kristian's thunder. It _might_ not work, but it might.

Comment: I'm afraid it didnt work. I've taken the easy way out and made them seperate, it works until I find something better: `$deleteEmp = "DELETE FROM JB_Employer WHERE Username='$fUsername'";
    $deleteJbs = "DELETE FROM JB_Jobseeker WHERE User_Name='$fUsername'"`

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference in syntaxes when FROM is used before or after the table names from which rows are to be deleted. These should work for deleting entries from both tables:

Using FROM after the table-names:

```
DELETE JB_Employer, JB_Jobseeker 
FROM JB_Employer INNER JOIN JB_Jobseeker ON JB_Employer.Username = JB_Jobseeker.User_Name
WHERE JB_Employer.Username= '$userName';
```

Using FROM before the table-names:

```
DELETE FROM JB_Employer, JB_Jobseeker 
USING JB_Employer INNER JOIN JB_Jobseeker ON JB_Employer.Username = JB_Jobseeker.User_Name
WHERE JB_Employer.Username= '$userName';
```

**EDIT 1**

The below section explains the queries for deleting the entries from both tables or either table.

Using FROM after the table-names:

```
DELETE JB_Employer, JB_Jobseeker 
FROM JB_Employer
LEFT JOIN JB_Jobseeker ON JB_Employer.Username = JB_Jobseeker.User_Name
WHERE JB_Employer.Username= '$userName';
```

Using FROM before the table-names:

```
DELETE FROM JB_Employer, JB_Jobseeker 
USING JB_Employer
LEFT JOIN JB_Jobseeker ON JB_Employer.Username = JB_Jobseeker.User_Name
WHERE JB_Employer.Username= '$userName';
```

Hope it works!

Comment: It didn't work I'm afraid, I tested it using a record that I know is there (test) and got this error: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE JB_Employer.Username= 'test'' at line 1 `

Comment: Right, a semi-colon at the wrong place. Could you fix it? Please see the updated query.

Comment: Hi, I altered the query and tried it again, it ran with no errors but it didn't return any records after I used a record that I know exists. :\

Comment: umm, I didn't follow. It is a DELETE query, it is not supposed to return any records

Comment: Sorry, I meant it didnt delete any records. This is what it returned: `0 row(s) deleted. ( Query took 0.0025 sec )`

Comment: hmm, I could think 2 reasons for it - one, there might not be any matching rows to delete. Two, the multi-table delete does not return the number of rows deleted; I however think that it does. Can you please verify by doing a select from your table?

Comment: There is definitely a record 'test' in the JB_Employer (Username) field, and its still there after the query runs.

Comment: Then there might not be a record by that username in JB_Jobseeker?

Comment: No there isn't, thats what I'm trying to do, the record is only in one of the tables, I need to write a code that establishes which table its in and then removes it :)

Comment: I think what you need is a LEFT JOIN then. Please try the query in EDIT 1 in my response

Comment: By the way, the EDIT assumes that the record will always be present in JB_Employer. That means, [1] both tables can have an entry for that username; [2] JB_Employer has but JB_Jobseeker doesn't have an entry for the username. It will never be that JB_Jobseeker has an entry and JB_Employer doesn't. Is that right?

Comment: I'm afraid not, the record will only ever be in one of the tables, (ethiher employer or jobseeker) so there will not always be a record present in JB_Employer.

Comment: @Kai, considering all the conditions, I think that a single DELETE query will be more complicated. How about keeping it simple and use 2 separate DELETE queries each for JB_Employer and JB_Jobseeker tables?

Comment: Yes that what I've ended up using. Sorry for wasting your time, I really appreciate the effort.

Comment: No problem @Kai. Indeed you helped me learn that a query might be more complicated than it initially seems ;-)